# Python: How do I write a dot over letters/variables, signifying the time derivative in physics?

Tags: python, time, derivative

I am looking for a way to place a bold dot above letters/variables to signify the time derivative. Ideally for both Python itself, but mainly for matplotlib axes.

I would expect something similar like:

```
print(u'1\u0305')
```

Although this is a very basic question, I cannot find anything, especially, because the term "dot notation" in Python is something completely different.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Python, rather, with your keyboard/OS.

Comment: In any case, this is the unicode code point: https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+0307

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The value (unicode code point) for a dot above letters ([**combining dot above**](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0307/index.htm)) is `'\u0307'`, so combining it with any letter will give you that letter but with a dot above.

```
dot = '\u0307'
print('n' + dot)  # ṅ
print('a' + dot)  # ȧ
print('v' + dot)  # v̇
```

An [**arrow right above**](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/20d7/index.htm) is often used if you want these to refer to a vector.

```
arrow = '\u20D7'
print('n' + arrow)  # n⃗
print('a' + arrow)  # a⃗
print('v' + arrow)  # v⃗
```

Alternatively, you could use a [**combining macron**](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/304/index.htm).

```
macron = '\u0304'
print('n' + macron)  # n̄
print('a' + macron)  # ā
print('v' + macron)  # v̄
```

Comment: Thank you! Is it also possible to just make the dot bold? like for example the bullet operator?

Answer (score 1):

Use LaTeX notation with matplotlib.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

plt.plot(np.random.random((5,)))
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel(r'$\dot{y}$')
```

[image]

You can name your variables using unicode characters like Ted showed, but in my opinion that just makes programming more difficult because standard keyboards don't have a way to type those characters easily.

Comment: Thank you! Is it also possible to make the dot bolder rather like the bullet operator instead of a dot?

Comment: The light dot looks a bit like dirt on the monitor.

Comment: @Thomas Surround it with `\mathbf{}` to make the thing bold

Comment: Thanks for the code to write bold, but I think this also makes the letter underneath bold, or can this also just be applied to the dot?